# The 3x3 grid is not showing for my tic tac toe in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm starting another project for beginner coding: TicTacToe.

I was following a how-to tutorial on YouTube but some of my results came out differently and I'm having trouble pinpointing where I've made the error.

**Problem**

- The word "Tic Tac Toe is showing on the top like in the given img: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GiUO.png)

  How it's supposed to look : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLBnZ.png)
- The grid is not showing a 3x3 grid.

---

Below would be my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- It's now connected to CSS file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe.css"
<title>Tic Tac Toe </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>

    <div class="status-action">
        <div class="status"> x is next </div>
        <div class=" reset"> Reset </div>
    </div>
<!-- put "div.etc-etc" then press "tab" and it'll automatically give you the whole tag-->
    <div class="game-grid"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        
</div>
<!-- It's now connected to JS file-->
<script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}


body {  
color: #545454;
display: flex; 
font-family: sans-serif;
justify-content: center;
}

.container {
background-color: #14BDAC;
margin: 50px;
padding: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.title {
text-align: center;}
.title span{
color: #F2EBD3;
}


.status-action {
 display: flex; 
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 25px;
justify-content: space-around; 
}

.reset {
cursor: pointer; 
.reset:hover {
color: #F2EBD3;
}

.game-grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-gap: 15px; 
}

.game-cell {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background: aquamarine;
}
```

This would be the video I'm following for additional resource: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rzhcb4M9-0Q?start=980&end=1240)

 (hopefully the video starts at *16:20* and ends around *20:40*)

---

Again, if the way I posted the question is incorrect please edit and let me know where I've gone wrong so that I can do better next time. 
 Thank you!

*I don't know why it's showing, "Tic Tac Toe Tic Tac Toe" under "!DOCTYPE HTML" 
I tried figuring that out as well but was unable to find out the problem.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting Tic Tac Toe twice as you have not closed the link tag in the head section:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe.css"></link>`

Also your grid is properly displayed as some of the closing tags are not on the proper places.

CSS:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
}


body {  
color: #545454;
display: flex; 
font-family: sans-serif;
justify-content: center;
}

.container {
background-color: #14BDAC;
margin: 50px;
padding: 50px;
border-radius: 25px;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}

.title {
text-align: center;
}
.title span{
color: #F2EBD3;
}


.status-action {
 display: flex; 
margin-top: 25px;
font-size: 25px;
justify-content: space-around; 
}

.reset {
cursor: pointer; 
}
.reset:hover {
color: #F2EBD3;
}

.game-grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-gap: 15px; 
}

.game-cell {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background: aquamarine;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- It's now connected to CSS file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe.css"></link>
<title>Tic Tac Toe </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>

    <div class="status-action">
        <div class="status"> x is next </div>
        <div class=" reset"> Reset </div>
    </div>
<!-- put "div.etc-etc" then press "tab" and it'll automatically give you the whole tag-->
    <div class="game-grid">
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
        <div class= "game-cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- It's now connected to JS file-->
<script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't see that careless error for the link! Thank you for spotting that out as well as the error in my post! 

But could you please explain a bit more about my problem with the grid? I'm still not quite following where the error lies.

Comment: You have not placed some of the closing tags and not closed some brackets in the proper places. Like in the styles `.reset` you have not closed the curley bracket, for `<div class="game-grid" >` You closed the div tag on the same line and thus the `div game-cell` are not enclosed in the `game-grid` tag.

Comment: I didn't do anything to fix the .reset, but I finally understood what you meant about the <div> tag. I fixed that part and now my grid is showing. Thank you !